# When can I use the emergency sick leave provided by HR 6201?

Tags: united-states, employment, human-resources

[H.R. 6201](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/6201) provides 80 hours of emergency sick leave for certain eligible purposes. Assuming a person works for an eligible employer and wishes to use this emergency sick leave for an eligible purpose, how soon can they use it?

To my eye, there seem to be two relevant things:

- Sec. 5102 says that this leave "is available immediately".
- Sec. 5108 says, "The emergency paid sick time requirements take effect not later than 15 days after the enactment of this division."

I'm not sure how to reconcile these two things. Section 5102 seems (to me) to mean that the leave should be available to employees as of 3/18, while Section 5108 seems to mean that it could be available on or before April 2 (15 days after March 18).

Comment: Considering that it is April 17, I'm not sure it matters. Are you asking for historical purposes?

Comment: @RonBeyer It's mostly for my curiosity about how this kind of thing works.I imagine that in some companies this leave is only now being processed, so it may have practical import for someone.